# IndyTCP delphi array of objects exchanging

Tags: delphi, serialization, tcp, memorystream

I'm sorry I know that I ask too many questions, but tomorrow (actually today cause in my coutry it's 2:00 am right now) I need to show to my teacher what I started to make e.t.c. So as I asked in previous questions I need to send from server to client some data.
But it nothing appers in server's memo field after thatt `memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(arrOf[1]));`

I was trying to send it like that on client

```
procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: array of integer; i:integer;
begin
  setLength(arrOf, 11);
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    arrOf[i]:=random(100);

  msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    msRecInfo.Write(arrOf, SizeOf(arrOf));
    idTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo);
  finally
     msRecInfo.Free;
  end;

end;
```

on server

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
   msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: array of Integer; i:integer;
begin
  msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, False);
    SetLength(arrOf,11);
    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
    msRecInfo.Read(arrOf, SizeOf(arrof));
  finally
    memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(arrOf[1]));
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;    
end;
```

Please could you help me to solve this problem and to find some examples of how to send arrays of different types/classes?

Comment: Is this something to get you started?, [Exchanging Data over the Network using Delphi - Part 2](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa020403a.htm).

Comment: Did you ever examined (e.g. Debugger) if the result of SizeOf( arrOf )  is the same you would expect?

Comment: @LURD quite not that thing which I need but thank you

Comment: Haven't you got your client and server mixed up

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ups sorry, now I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rufo already explained, you are not writing the array into, and reading the array out of, the `TMemoryStream` correctly.

Worse, you are not sending the `TMemoryStream` over the socket correctly, either.  The default parameters of `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` are not compatible with each other.  By default, `Write(TStream)` **does not** send the `TStream.Size` value.  However, the default parameters of `ReadStream()` (which are the same values that you are passing in explicitally) tell it to read the first few bytes and interpret them as the `Size`, which would be very wrong in this example.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: Array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(arrOf, 11);
  for i := Low(arrOf) to High(arrOf) do
    arrOf[i] := random(100);

  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    msRecInfo.WriteBuffer(arrOf[0], Length(arrOf) * SizeOf(Integer));
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo, 0, True);
  finally
     msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: Array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, False);
    SetLength(arrOf, msRecInfo.Size div SizeOf(Integer));
    if Lenth(arrOf) > 0 then
    begin
      msRecInfo.Position := 0;
      msRecInfo.ReadBuffer(arrOf[0], Length(arrOf) * SizeOf(Integer));
    end;
  finally
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;    
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, get rid of the `TMemoryStream` and send the individual `Integer` values by themselves:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  arrOf: Array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(arrOf, 11);
  for i := Low(arrOf) to High(arrOf) do
    arrOf[i] := random(100);

  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Length(arrOf));
  for I := Low(arrOf) to High(arrOf) do
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(arrOf[i]);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  arrOf: Array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
  SetLength(arrOf, i);
  for i := Low(arrOf) to High(arrOf) do
    arrOf[i] := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
  ...
end;
```

Now, with that said, accessing the `TMemo` directly in the `OnExecute` event handler is not thread-safe.  `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  The `OnExecute` event is triggered in the context of a worker thread, not the main thread.  UI components, like `TMemo`, cannot be safely accessed from outside of the main thread.  You can use Indy's `TIdNotify` or `TIdSync` class to synchronize with the main thread, eg:

```
type
  TMemoSync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FLine: String;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  end;

procedure TMemoSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(FLine);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  with TMemoSync.Create do try
    FLine := IntToStr(arrOf[1]);
    Synchronize;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

If you do not synchronize with the main thread, bad things can happen.

Comment: +1 excellent answer. You could also get rid of the array and just send the random numbers ;o)

Comment: Thanks! `Alternatively, get rid of the TMemoryStream` I cant' I gonna to exchange arrays of objects of some classes between server and client

Comment: But how can I able to see sended values?!

Comment: I told you how - you can use the `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class to safely access the `TMemo`.

Comment: I added an example of how to use `TIdSync`. `TIdNotify` is used similarly, except you override `DoNotify()` instead of `DoSynchronize()`, and call `Notify()` instead of `Synchronize()`. `TIdSync` is synchronous, `Synchornize()` does not return until the main thread has executed `DoSynchronize()`. `TIdNotify` is asynchronous, `Notify()` queues the request and returns immediately, and then `DoNotify()` is executed by the main thread at a later time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh, well, nice but it can't find such components. I'm using XE3 right now.

Comment: Remy: `The default parameters of TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream) and TIdIOHandler.ReadStream() are not compatible with each other.` Why?!

Comment: @RemyLebeau i showed this today to my teacher. Well it sends the right array but when server recieves it there different values in it! Huh he was trying to fix it but with no success(actually he is into math modeling and stuff he dosen't know delphi good so). So why could it be? Because of things not synchronized too?

Comment: `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` are not components, they are utility classes. They are declared in the `IdSync` unit.

Comment: The default behaviors of `Write(TStream)` and `ReadStream()` are different because they are commonly used for different purposes. It is more common to send a stream without sending its `Size`, and it is more common to read a stream when its `Size` is being sent. That is just the default behaviors. You can override the defaults to make `Write()` send the `Size`, and make `ReadStream()` not expect the `Size` to be sent.

Comment: We can't diagnose your server problems without seeing what code you actually turned in. Did you verify that `ReadLongInt()` is returning the correct values that `Write()` is sending?

Comment: @RemyLebeau well with `Integer` it says `RangeCHeckError` just during connection! Oh :c [Here's a full code](http://pastebin.com/gKGuNQ87) if you interested in

Comment: Your server code is failing because your client code is calling `Socket.WriteLn(DateTimeToStr(Now))` in the `TIdTCPClient.OnConnected` event, but your server code is never reading that string line. The first call to `ReadLongInt()` in the `OnExecute` event will read the first 4 bytes of the date/time string and interpret them as an integer value, which is wrong. You need to add a call to `IOHandler.ReadLn()` inside of your server `OnConnect` event handler.

Comment: Also, your server `OnConnect` and `OnDisconect` event handlers need to use `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` to access `Label1` safely. What I said about them was not limited to just the `TMemo` usage.

Answer (score 3):

This is your Main Problem here

```
msRecInfo.Write( arrOf, SizeOf( arrOf ) );
```

You write the pointer-address of the array into the stream ... i dont't think thats your goal.

If you want to put the content of the array into the stream you should use

```
msRecInfo.Write( arrOf[ Low( arrOf ) ], SizeOf( Integer ) * Length( arrOf ) );
```

Why? You have to point to the first position of the data (first element of the array), and you have to calculate the length of the data.

On the receiving part it is just the same

```
msRecInfo.Read( arrOf[ Low( arrOf ) ], SizeOf( Integer ) * Length( arrOf ) );
```

PS: This may work well in this special case, but to be safe, you should send at first, the length of all data, so the receiver knows, when message is complete

Comment: did you checked with the debugger? or try memo1.Lines.Add( IntToStr( msRecInfo.Size ) ); just to see, how much bytes are received ... and if

Comment: I don't know how to use debugger during client-server exchanging actually. but i mad as you said `memo1.Lines.Add( IntToStr( msRecInfo.Size ) );` and there are still nothing. hmm.

Comment: so what do you think? ... the server never gets the data or the event is not connected to the component, you have to check your code

Comment: I added in `procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);` this `memo1.Lines.Add('Test');` and it worked after client conected to server. I mean it shows that it's connected, yes? But data from memorystream just not reading/

Comment: You are not sending the `TMemoryStream` correctly, so you either end up raising an exception if `ReadStream()` tries to allocate too much memory for the output `TStream`, or `ReadStream()` deadlocks waiting for more data than is actually being sent.  See my answer.